# Profiling build on maven 3?

Tags: maven, profiling

I am reasking this question for maven 3:

[Profiling Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681968/profiling-maven)

I want to know how much time is spent for each mojo / phase / project.

There is http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3547 and http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4639 but I dont know about their state.

I applied MNG-3547 to apache-maven-2.2.1 and it works fine. I gather the profiling data that is emitted, parse and analyse it (using scala).

Now we are migrating to maven 3.

**Are there newer / better approaches to profile a maven3 build, or should I port the patch?**

Thanks in advance, Bastl.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369233/incremental-build-in-jenkins

Comment: @alexsmail I don't get why this is related?

Comment: you want to speed up your build, my link addresses this issues through incremental build (I didn't get an answer whether it actually works, though).

Comment: Actually I want to know why it takes so long. I want to measure before I act.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I don't know if this is really a direct answer based on Maven alone, but I do know that Sonatype's Maven 3 work on the Hudson plugin did include profiling information for a build.  If you use the Maven 3 integration for Hudson you will be able to see how long your Maven builds spend in each goal.